# Permitir ruta, bloquear IPs

Tags: nginx

Tengo una configuración en nginx para permitir solo el paso a determinadas ips:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_for !~* "^(81.47.168.127|80.32.119...)") { return 404; }
```

Esto funciona. Pero también quiero que, independientemente de la IP a la que se acceda, siempre se pueda acceder a una ruta concreta:

```
domain.com/app
```

y esto es lo que no sé como hacer.

Si accedes a domain.com desde la ip 81.47.168.127 puedes llegar a la página, si accedes desde otra IP te devuelve un error 404 (bien), pero si accedo a domain.com/app desde otra IP debería cargar la página.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

¡gracias!

Comment: Hola, para permitir el acceso a una ruta específica independientemente de la dirección IP, puedes agregar una nueva directiva de ubicación en su archivo de configuración de Nginx.
La directiva de ubicación debe tener la ruta que desea permitir y la directiva allow all. Aquí hay un ejemplo:

location /app {
    allow all;
}
Mira a ver si es eso, si he entendido bien

Comment: Hola eso ya lo probé y no funciono

Comment: Daba un error del tipo: _"allow" directive is not allowed here in_

Comment: indica como esta el archivo de conf. Entiendo que es algo del tipo:
location /app {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
}